# Why dereferencing a unique_ptr won't modify the original object

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

See the following example, I've used a unique pointer and a raw pointer to `a`, my question is, why does the raw pointer work but not the unique pointer? If I want to modify string `a` like a reference by using the `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`, what should I do?

Example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string a = "aaa";
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<string>(a);
    auto ptr2 = &a;
    cout << "before, a: " << a << endl;
    *ptr += "bbb";
    cout << "After, a: " << a << endl;
    *ptr2 += "ccc";
    cout << "after 2, a: " << a << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
before, a: aaa
After, a: aaa
after 2, a: aaaccc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` must refer to a dynamically allocated object (so that it can safely delete it in the end). That's why `std::make_unique` creates a new object.

This will [work up to your expectations](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff63d23f6bca7d6d):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    string* a = new string("aaa");
    std::unique_ptr<string> ptr(a);
    auto ptr2 = a;
    cout << "before, a: " << *a << endl;
    *ptr += "bbb";
    cout << "After, a: " << *a << endl;
    *ptr2 += "ccc";
    cout << "after 2, a: " << *a << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
before, a: aaa
After, a: aaabbb
after 2, a: aaabbbccc
```

Answer (score 9):

`std::make_unique<string>(a);` will `new` a brand new `std::string` (initialized from `a`), which is pointed by `ptr` later. So the object is modified by `*ptr += "bbb"`, but it has nothing to do with the original object `a`.

You could confirm that the object pointed by `unique_ptr` **is** modified, via the following demo:

```
string* pa = new string("aaa");
unique_ptr<string> ptr(pa);
auto ptr2 = pa;
cout << "before, *pa: " << *pa << endl;
*ptr += "bbb";
cout << "After, *pa: " << *pa << endl;
*ptr2 += "ccc";
cout << "after 2, *pa: " << *pa << endl;
```

Result:

```
before, *pa: aaa
After, *pa: aaabbb
after 2, *pa: aaabbbccc
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/TLPE27568)

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::make_unique<string>(a)` creates a completely new `std::string` object and initializes it with the contents of `a`. The new string and the old `a` have no connection with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Make unique constructs an object of the type T and wraps it in a unique_ptr. You may be actually making a copy of "a" without you noticing it.